# Run cron job in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, cron

I have this simple cron job function:

```
var job = new cronJob('* * * * * *', function () {
  // do some form of stuffs...
 }, function () {
     console.log('DelCron Job finished.');
 }, true, 'Asia/Calcutta');
```

This will run every second.

My question:

In the mysql database i have one table called "profsms" in this table i have **scheduledTime** field.

If scheduledTime = 18/01/2018 10.00AM

I want to run that cron job by that time dynamically is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically? what happens if  scheduledTime<  {your_time} OR scheduledTime > {your_time}

Comment: I want to make my cron job works according to the **scheduledTime**

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your time to the `cronjob` schedule string.

Assuming the string to look like this

```
# ┌────────────── second (optional)
# │ ┌──────────── minute
# │ │ ┌────────── hour
# │ │ │ ┌──────── day of month
# │ │ │ │ ┌────── month
# │ │ │ │ │ ┌──── year
# │ │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │ │
# * * * * * *
```

Since you have `(dd/mm/yyyy hour.minute(AM/PM))` `(18/01/2018 10.00AM)`

```
const convertTimeToCronJobString = (time) => {
    let retString = '';
    const dmy = time.split(' ')[0];
    const d = dmy.split('/')[0];
    const m = dmy.split('/')[1];
    const y = dmy.split('/')[2];

    const hm = time.split(' ')[1];
    const h = hm.split(';')[0];
    let min = '';
    if (hm.split(';')[1].indexOf('AM') > -1) { // AM
      min = hm.split(';')[1].replace('AM','');
    } else if (hm.split(';')[1].indexOf('AM') > -1) { // PM
      min = hm.split(';')[1].replace('PM','');
      min = String(Number(min) + 12);
    }
    return `0 ${min} ${h} ${d} ${m} ${y}` // you want to start at 0th secound
}
```

Now you just need to send your `scheduledTime` into this function and that will return you a cronjobString. Use that string to schedule your task.

Comment: how to send my scheduledTime? can you explain it will helpful to me :)

Comment: you will have to use mysql client for node. And then read the table that has the scheduledTime in it! 
This may be helpful
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql